# Formatting an output string using TYPE in V+

Tags: string, v+

If i have a number in `V+`, say a float:

```
a = 4.562342354
TYPE a
```

When using `TYPE` I will print to the monitor window:

```
. 4.562342
```

How do i format this output with a set number of significant figures? Is the syntax similar to `c` with `%f`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the format specifier `/Fn.m` from the V+ documentation:

> /Fn.m Output values in fixed-point notation (for example, -123.4) in fields n
>   spaces wide, with m digits in the fractional parts.

So for example:

```
TYPE /F5.3, a
```

Gives you

```
. 4.562
```